# PasswordEncoder : The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using `Spring-boot 2.2.6.RELEASE` and I have this two simple classes:

```
@Configuration
public class CUserService {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public CUserService(PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder)
    {
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public CWebSecurityConfiguration(PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder)
    {
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

}
```

When i compile, i get :

```
Description:  
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:  
CUserService defined in file [G:\...\classes\com\example\Spring_Authentification\CUserService.class]
```

Why i get this error ? Where is the `cycle` ?!

2 - If i add this line to `application.properties` file :

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

and add this `@Bean declaration` in the two classes (CUserService, CWebSecurityConfiguration )

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

When i compile i get the following error :

```
 Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Comment: put your `PasswordEncoder` bean declaration in a different class

Comment: @pvpkiran Ok, thanks, i will try this

Comment: @pvpkiran by doing tthis, i'm getting a new error :  `Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.Spring_Authentification.CUserService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.`

Comment: show the class how you have done. edit the question and add that detail

Comment: Put this bean @configuration annotated class

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib Thanks.